# Regex to find a string like this (MUSI110532022-3SV1SEM1) - containing brackets ,numbers, letters and dash

Tags: regex

I am new to regex.

I am trying to find strings such as (MUSI110532022-3SV1SEM1) in a free text field.
The string may appear in any location and it may also be preceded by other text in a bracket.

Is there any regex expression to identify such a string at any location within a field?

I already tried [a-zA-Z]{4}d{5}$ but it didn't work and I think it was because I need to account for the brackets?

Any help very gratefully received.

Comment: Just guessing - `\([a-zA-Z]{4}\d{9}-\d[a-zA-Z]{2}\d[a-zA-Z]{3}\d\)`? See https://regex101.com/r/KeA9TE/1

Comment: "*I already tried [a-zA-Z]{4}d{5}$*" but you neither have 5 digits in your pattern, nor is that the end of the string...